# What is the difference between StructureMap.MVC5 and StructureMap 4.5.2 in Nuget Package Manager

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, structuremap4

In Nuget there are StructureMap.MVC5 and StructureMap(version 4.5.2). There is only version difference or something else?

Comment: Have you read the descriptions of the NuGet packages?

Comment: Yes but not found any satisfy description